# Customize sysctl parameters by user

Tags: kernel, parameter, sysctl

I know there's `*.conf` file in `/usr/lib/sysctl.d` and/or `/etc/sysctl.d` folders ready to establish kernel parameters on boot. But they are general; 
what I want is to customize some of these parameters (say, `net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all`) depending on the user who is in, but I want per-user kernel parameters.
Is it possible or what I'm saying is a complete silliness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What @Tomasz says it's true: those are kernel parameters, so they are **"*unique*"**!

Anyway, you can achieve some result with that limit

---

*...in the OP, @Osqui doesn't say users are simultaneously logged in...*

---

by sketching out a script executed when users login/logout using the `sysctl` command

Comment: Thanks! It's a good tip!

Answer (score 3):

These are kernel parameters and the kernel is shared by all users. As long as your system is supposed to be used by multiple users simultaneously there's no way these parameters could have multiple values at once. And there are normally many various users (personalities) active (owing processes) even if there's only one human user in front of the screen.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected that but thanks for clarification!